# How can I add space from unallocated to extended?

Tags: gparted

I have a 12 GB partition with Linux installed in it, but I started runnung out of space. I tried to use `gparted` on a CD, but for some reason, I could not add space to the extended partition.
This is what my partition table looks like:

```
/dev/sda3     : extended        12    GB    
/dev/sda5     : ext4            10    GB    
/dev/sda6     : linux-swap      2     GB           
unallocated   :                 69,77 GB
```

i want to add unallocated to `/dev/sda5`. I tried to resize both `dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda5`, but no free space is shown in the window.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using Gparted from a Live CD:

1. Select the swap partition
2. In the Partition menu, click on "swapoff"
3. Delete the swap partition
4. Recreate swap at the end of Unallocated (faster than moving it)

   Optional: Turn swap back on
5. Resize sda5 as desired

Comment: I didn't check if that was swap, obviously your idea is better than mine ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. Extend the extended partition.
2. Move the 2 GB partition at the end of the extended partition.
3. Extend the 10 GB partition.

That will normally do the trick.