# How do i add an unallocated partition to another partition

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, hard-drive

[image]

[How can I add space from unallocated to extended?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120347/how-can-i-add-space-from-unallocated-to-extended)

Can someone please simplify the process? I have no idea what to do. I just deleted my windows partition and i want to add it to my Ubuntu one. Also what is the middle partition used for? because when i boot now, i get options to do linux, or generic, or x86 and stuff.  Is that safe to delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I can answer your questions:

1. The unallocated space is space on your hard disk that is not being used by any partitions; think of it as "blank space". To increase the size of that partition, boot from your live DVD or USB and open GParted. In the bottom list of partitions, right click the "extended" and "linux-swap" partitions and Unmount each of them. Select your Extended partition, click the "⇥" button (move or resize), and with your mouse click'n'drag the left side of the blue box all the way to the left. In the same way, use the Move or Resize (⇥) tool to click'n'drag the red linux-swap partition to move it all the way to the left, and then click'n'drag the *right* side of the blue partition again to close it in. You may have to close the tool and select the partition you want if it does not allow you to play with both partitions simaltaneously. Then you have a small light blue box containing the red box, expect it's all the way on the left of your unallocated space.
2. Select the *dark blue* partition, click the ⇥ button again, and click'n'drag the left side as far to the left as you can.
3. Click the green check mark, and apply the operations. This will be a long process, at least a few minutes, but you will see the progress.
4. Reboot. You may have trouble booting. If that happens, boot from your live DVD or USB again and use this guide to re-install the GRUB boot loader: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
5. You don't need to worry about any of the options on the GRUB menu for a normal boot. You will only need to use the top one, so when you see the menu, just press Enter. Your other options are Rescue mode, where you can make repairs if a normal boot doesn't work, or a Memtest.
   I hope that helps!