# Adding unallocated parition to an extened parition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I am trying to extend my Ubuntu Partition.

This is what my partitions looks like,

[image]

So I booted to live cd and used gparted to work with the partition.
My problem now is that I deleted the swap partition as instructed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/120381/235458).

But my problem is I was told I can't add new partition, and now I am stuck not sure how to procede

I wanted to add the 101.86GB unallocated to my ubuntu install located at /dev/sda5

Also I am dual booting with Windows 7 /dev/sda3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below steps to add 101 GB unallocated space to your Ubuntu `/dev/sda5` partition,

- Right-click on the `/dev/sda4` extended partition and then select Resize/Move option.Move the left arrow to the extreme left so that the unallocated space will comes into the extended partition.
- Now the 101 GB unallocated space was combined with the 1.96 GB unallocated space.(101+1.96 GB)
- Atlast right-click on the `/dev/sda5` to add the (101+1.96 GB) unallocated space to your Ubuntu partition.

Comment: I followed your instruction and successfully managed to add it to my Ubuntu partition. Unfortunately I don't what happened but grub loader was deleted also I guess, so I went to fix it.

Then when I tried to reboot again, it doesn't show grub loader. So what happens now is I keep on booting to my Windows partition

Comment: try the second option in [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).That's all.