# Limit on number of primary partitions: install Windows 7 32-bit after Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, boot-partition

My Lenovo T420 came with preinstalled Windows 10 and then I installed Ubuntu 16.04 for a dual boot machine. I tried installing Windows 7 Professional in the unallocated partition using the Windows installer (the unallocated partition created by shrinking Windows 10 by all the unused space. Since then I've cleaned up Windows 10 so there is more free space seen in screenshot below). The 61.95G partition I installed to can be seen here:

[image: screenshot_Gparted]

But then my GRUB was gone or damaged so it would only give me a choice between Windows 7 or 10 when booting.

I uninstalled Windows 7 and don't remember exactly but think I did boot repair to get my GRUB menu back to choose between Ubuntu and Windows 10.

I want to install Windows 7 because I have a USB device (Seiko Instruments portable translator for Japanese with PASORAMA function which installs an app so I can use the translator from a GUI on my desktop), but drivers are only available up to Windows 7 32-bit (not even Windows 7 64-bit). I tried installing Windows 7 via VMware, but could not access the USB properly, i.e. could not install the PASORAMA app. Thus I want to install Windows 7 in the partition pointed to above so I can triple boot into Windows 7 and try installing the device software there and do my translation work (the device has to be connected via USB while using the app).

I don't have a separate boot partition. As you can see the Windows 10 systems partition takes up the first 500MB and then the Windows 10 partition of 286.13G so as I read somewhere, I cannot shrink that to get the boot partition within the first 100G of the disk. I kept searching and learned that if I format the unallocated partition to NTFS before installing Windows 7 to it, then Windows 7 would not create a separate systems partition.  I thought that would leave GRUB alone, but I'm afraid to try it without a solid answer because it took me a while to get GRUB back last time.

Hence my questions are:

1. In my case, how can I install Win 7 to the unallocated partition and keep GRUB?
2. In this case, will the GRUB menu show the 3 OS's and let me choose the OS?
3. Am I going to go over a limit to the number of partitions on sda (a Samsung EVO 850 SSD)?

I have a USB drive with the Ubuntu iso also with Boot Repair installed on it (installed the last time I had to use it to boot and repair/restore GRUB).

More about my machine: I replaced HDD with SSD (so the SSD is sda as in the screenshot), replaced optical drive with HDD (using it to store files).

Update: I just read that easyBCD will not work with Win Professional

Update: I have two primary partitions on MBR disk (/dev/sda) where I want to put the Windows 7 per the screenshot:

[image: parted output in terminal]

So I'm guessing that even if Windows 7 installs and creates its own separate systems partition I'll be at the limit of 4 primary partitions.

Update: based on comment from oldfred below, I flagged the newly created NTFS partition as "boot".
I will update this afternoon after trying the install to that partition `/dev/sda4`

[image: screenshot_Gparted]

Update:  Successfully installed Windows 7 from an installation CD, booted from a USB with an Ubuntu ISO and boot repair installed to run boot repair and now I have GRUB menu with all three OS's showing.  On my machine I had to then download drivers for WiFi and such on to USB in Ubuntu and install them on Windows 7 but otherwise there were no problems.  As a newbie who spun my wheels for a couple of days trying to install Nvidia drivers for CUDA to work, I was hesitant to try anything without asking here first.  Thanks!

Update:  I shrank my Windows 10 partition using Gparted to make space for the partition for Windows 7.  Perhaps that corrupted Windows 10 because it will not shutdown but will restart.  For the time being, if I want to shutdown from Windows 10, I restart, boot Ubuntu and then shutdown.  I also forgot to mention that I did preformat the Windows 7 partition as NTFS and put the boot flag on it in Gparted.  Windows 7 is on `/dev/sda4` without a separate Systems partition.

Update:  The SSD `/dev/sda` has the three OS's on it and I have a HDD in the optical drive where I store files in a NTFS partition and ext4 partition. However, it seems that I can only access files from the NTFS partition from Windows 7, Windows 10 and even Ubuntu.  That is strange because I thought Ubuntu can only access files from an ext4 partition.

Comment: I looked through both of those and still wondering if it applies to my situation of having three OS's with possible problems of limits on number of primary partitions.

Comment: The vast majority of computers that come with Windows 8 or later pre-installed use the GUID Partition Table (GPT), which doesn't suffer from a 4-primary-partition limit. In fact, GPT doesn't make a distinction between primary, extended, and logical partitions; you've just got "partitions" (with no qualifier), although GParted and some other tools insist on applying the "primary" adjective to GPT partitions. + [How can I add space from unallocated to extended?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120347/how-can-i-add-space-from-unallocated-to-extended)

Comment: Thanks Karel.  I'm guessing I can check whether it is GPT or MBR with Gparted or even diskmgmt in Win 10 and then just go ahead and follow instructions on links provided by commenters.

Comment: actually mine was MBR after checking with `sudo parted -l` as it showed Partition Table: msdos and that is MBR according to this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120221/gpt-or-mbr-how-do-i-know So apparently I am limited to 4 primary partitions.  Now I need to find out whether each partition is primary as of now and how to change their type or choose for the unallocated to squeeze Win 7 in there.

Comment: Windows 7 DVD only installs in BIOS boot mode to MBR partitioned drives. And to a primary NTFS partition with boot flag. Or two partitions one smaller boot and then main install. DVD can be converted to UEFI, by copying to flash drive and moving & editing some files names. You still have primary partition 4 left. But if UEFI hardware probably should have installed everything in UEFI mode with gpt partitioning.

Comment: @oldfred, that makes sense even a Linux rookie like myself.  I'll have to research the second part about conversion to UEFI as my machine boots from Bios.

Comment: If system came with Windows 10, it must be an UEFI system. But once drive is MBR, then Windows can only be BIOS boot. Difficult to change unless you want to totally reinstall. So may be best at this time to just install in BIOS mode to sda4?

Comment: @oldfred I used the Samsung software that came with the SSD to clone my Windows 10 from HDD, then installed Ubuntu and now installed Windows 7.  I did exactly as you mention.

Comment: Ubuntu has built-in support for accessing NTFS partitions.

Comment: @karel, that is really cool to know!